# Delete ListView Item on Click from database and List

Tags: java, android, listview

In this App there is a main activity consisting of buttons that shows categories involves in food app. We had just worked on "Burgers" Category yet. After clicking Burger Category, another activity will open with the name "Burgers.java" There will be add new button and a listview which is showing data from database.
When we click on add new, an activity naming "AddBurgers.java" will open where we can enter price and name of new burger into database and it will be also shown in listview.

I have made "ListAdapter.java" and "SQLiteHelper.java" activities which are helping in adding data to database and then show it in listview.

Now the problem we are facing is that, we want to delete the item of listview on item long press and wants to show data of item in notification panel on item click. Further if we click on the notification, it will open the lisview.
  **Burgers.java**

```
    public class Burgers extends Activity {

SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
Cursor cursor;
ListAdapter listAdapter ;
ListView LISTVIEW;

ArrayList<String> ID_Array;
ArrayList<String> NAME_Array;
ArrayList<String> PRICE_Array;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_burgers);

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(Burgers.this, AddBurgers.class));
        }
    });

    LISTVIEW = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

    ID_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

    NAME_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

    PRICE_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this);

    LISTVIEW.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    ShowSQLiteDBdata() ;

    super.onResume();
}

private void ShowSQLiteDBdata() {

    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME+"", null);

    ID_Array.clear();
    NAME_Array.clear();
    PRICE_Array.clear();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            ID_Array.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.COL_1)));

            NAME_Array.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.COL_2)));

            PRICE_Array.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.COL_3)));


        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    listAdapter = new ListAdapter(Burgers.this,

            ID_Array,
            NAME_Array,
            PRICE_Array
    );

    LISTVIEW.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    cursor.close();
}

}
```

**ListAdapter.java**

```
    public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<String> ID;
ArrayList<String> Name;
ArrayList<String> Price;


public ListAdapter(
        Context context2,
        ArrayList<String> id,
        ArrayList<String> name,
        ArrayList<String> price
)
{

    this.context = context2;
    this.ID = id;
    this.Name = name;
    this.Price = price;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ID.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View child, ViewGroup parent) {

    Holder holder;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    if (child == null) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_row_design, null);

        holder = new Holder();

        holder.ID_TextView = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.Name_TextView = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        holder.PriceTextView = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.textView11);

        child.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (Holder) child.getTag();
    }
    holder.ID_TextView.setText(ID.get(position));
    holder.Name_TextView.setText(Name.get(position));
    holder.PriceTextView.setText(Price.get(position));

    return child;
}



public class Holder {

    TextView ID_TextView;
    TextView Name_TextView;
    TextView PriceTextView;
}
}
```

**SQLiteHelper.java**

```
    public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Afoods.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "burger_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "PRICE";

public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, PRICE TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String name,String price) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,price);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

}
```

**AddBurgers.java**

```
public class AddBurgers extends AppCompatActivity {

SQLiteHelper myDb;
EditText editName,editPrice;
Button btnAddData;
Button btnviewAll;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_burgers);


    myDb = new SQLiteHelper(this);

    editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editPrice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    btnAddData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btnviewAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    AddData();

    btnviewAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(AddBurgers.this, Burgers.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}

public  void AddData() {
    btnAddData.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editName.getText().toString(),
                            editPrice.getText().toString() );
                    if(isInserted == true)
                        Toast.makeText(AddBurgers.this,"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(AddBurgers.this,"Data not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}
}
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated. I have been working on it for 15 days. The code I mentioned above runs perfectly. I just need to add delete and notification function in it.

Comment: Check below answer, and you may ask several questions to reach what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> we want to delete the item of listview on item long press

Implement `setOnItemLongClickListener` for listView just like you did for `onItemClickListener`. On long click perform `delete` query on your database similar to what you did for `insert` query.

> wants to show data of item in notification panel on item click

Add code for notification in `onItemClickListener`. For showing notification you have to study [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html) how notifications are created.

> Further if we click on the notification, it will open the lisview

You will have to create an Intent for PendingIntent and launch an activity(`Burgers.java`) which will show the listView. It is explained clearly [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#action).

Comment: For better code writing use `insert` and `delete` methods provided by the `SQLiteOpenHelper` instead of `insertData`.

Comment: Probably will have to set `android:longClickable="true"` in xml file as well.